# Play cannot find my controller

Tags: playframework-2.6

I have a controller

```
class UserController @Inject()(userRepo: Repository[UUID, User],cc: ControllerComponents)(implicit exec: ExecutionContext) extends AbstractController(cc){
```

When I try to use it as `new controllers.UserController(userRepository, controllerComponents)` then Play gives error `cannot resolve symbol UserController`. I am trying to use Dependency Injection.

I am also trying to use `controllers.AssetsComponents` but get the same error for that. I might have messed up the configuration somewhere I suppose.

I have checked that `routesGenerator` is commented in `build.sbt`

Comment: Instead of using creating a controller object by constructor you should inject it. follow this links: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaRouting#dependency-injection

Comment: I want to inject it at compile time. The code above is what I suppose we have to write in Apploader. The process requires instantiating the controller and then dependencies which play will later inject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my custom app loader where I was creating instances of my controllers, I had to comment `import play.api._` in the file. I don't know thought why including `play.api._` was causing the issue!